# jasypt spring hibernate - what password is what?

Tags: spring, hibernate, encryption, jasypt

Im trying to use jasypt to encrypt some passwords in our properties file. Im following the guide on the jasypt website but I think Im messing up something with the passwords. Im hoping someone here can tell me Im doing it right or doing it wrong.  Right now... when I start up my jboss server I get an "invalid username/password" error when it tries to hit the database. Either the decrypt is failing or my setup is wrong.
Here is how things are setup.

I generated my encrypted password as follows:

```
c:\jasypt-1.9.2\bin\encrypt input=mydbpassword password=password   
----ENVIRONMENT----------------

Runtime: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08

-----ARGUMENTS-----------------
input: mydbpassword
password: password

------OUTPUT-------------------
N6Wz+z6fI24MagR5A4xNoH4gMh75Vo0
```

Question #1: Im assuming my database password goes in the "input". If so... then what is the password field used for??

My persistence.xml:

```
<property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagementConnectionProvider" />
<property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name" value="configurationHibernateEncryptor" />
```

My Spring Bean:

```
<bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
<property name="registeredName">
    <value>strongHibernateStringEncryptor</value>
</property>
<property name="algorithm">
    <value>PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES</value>
</property>
<property name="password">
    <value>password</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Question #2: Im assuming the "password" field from the encrypt command goes here? I cant imagine my DB password goes here since that defeats the purpose of the encryption. But then again... the docs really didnt say what that value was or is.

thanks to anyone who can help!

-Blake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the algorithm as well.

`c:\jasypt-1.9.2\bin\encrypt input=mydbpassword password=password  algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES`

Refer: http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html#Listing_algorithms

To work with `PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES` you need to install [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) into your JDK.

Parameter `password` is the encryption key which is what you need to decrypt your password in to plain text.

Comment: Hello. That first suggestion got my first app up and running. Worked like a charm. However, I have two more apps that deploy on my jboss server and neither of them work - with the exact same configuration. Im guessing the decrypt is failing since I get an "invalid username/password" from oracle. I have verified that the hibernateStringEncryptor bean deploys and my persistence.xml files are identical (same database password). Any thoughts on how I might be able to see what jasypt is decrypting or if it is even trying to decrypt it?  thanks!

Comment: Without looking at configurations can't say much. Just take a look at http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt-hibernate4/1.9.0/org/jasypt/hibernate4/encryptor/HibernatePBEStringEncryptor.html

Comment: Thanks for that - it did give me something else to try. I dont have a hibernate config like it talks about but I have the persistence.xml (Which I believe is the JPA version of the hibernate config?). I modified my connection.encryptor_registered_name in the persistence.xml to match the "registeredName" in the hibernateStringEncryptor bean. However, I still get the invalid username/password. It didnt match in my app that works. Can you think of any breakpoints I could set that might give me more info on what is going wrong with the jasypt decrypt? Thanks again for your time with this!